# Consigo usar arrays no SQL (Big Query)?

Tags: sql, array, while, arraylist, bigquery

bom dia!

Ainda não entendo tanto de SQL, mas lá vai...

Criei uma consulta gigantesca com WITH, no entanto, percorrer uma lista iria deixar a query "mais bonita", então queria saber se é possível trabalhar com um array e se sim, como faria um While com ele dentro do Big Query?

Desde já agradeço a atenção...

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: "se é possível trabalhar com um array e se sim, como faria um While com ele dentro do Big Query?" Se isto não é específico ...